# simple function for finding the next prime number using a while loop in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

first post here so hello world lol.

i starting learning c++ and doing some challenges. One i found is "find the next prime number" given an integer, make a function to  find the next sequential prime number eg if given 12 return 13, if given 24 return 29, if given a prime return that. I dont understand why the following block of code doesnt work (my guess is that two of the conditions

```
int nextPrime(int num) {

while (num % 2 !=0 && num %3 != 0 && num %4 != 0 && num %5 != 0 && num %6 != 0 && num %7 != 0 && num %8 != 0 && num %9);
         ++num;

return num;
```

}

its a relatively easy task, but the fact i dont know why its not working bothers me more than the fact it isnt working. Any help you lovely internet people can provide is most welcome.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check in the `while` condition?

Comment: *my guess is that two of the conditions...* What's your guess?

Comment: Why do you have `%4` and `%6`?  Hint: if a number is divisible by 2, it is also divisible by 4.  If a number is divisible by 2 and by 3, it is divisible by 6.  Use some math to reduce your complexity.

Comment: Your function makes no sense. Suppose `num=3`, a prime number. `num % 2 != 0` is true, so the function returns `3`.

Comment: @LHaurini no it wont return `3`, read the whole condition

Comment: @cigien the while loop is to check for a prime number, if mod number isnt zero for any of those numbers, should be a prime was my thinking (as to my guess, the function was returning numbers like 15 which is %5 =0 and %3 = 0, so somehow it returned, but im not sure.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews good idea, thank you. i only really need 2, 3 5 and 7.

Comment: See [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 1):

bool PrimeNumber(int n)
{for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
if(n%i==0){
return false
}
return true
}

Comment: If you check for divisibility by 2 before the loop, then you can have the loop start at 3 and increment by 2.  No need to check even numbers after 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

//check if number is prime divide by all number less than sqrt(n)
bool isprime(int n){
    for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            //not a prime return false then.
            return false;
        }
    }// its a prime number.
    return true;
}

int main() {
    
    int n = 12345;
    
    while(1){
        if(isprime(n)){
            cout << n <<endl;
            // id its a prime number we are done break the loop.
            break;
        }
        // increase n by 1. continue the loop untill the next prime.
        n+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually not useful. How about explaining why this solution works, and how it addresses the OP's question?

Comment: added inline comment

Comment: Where did you learn to use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?  It is non-standard and a megalithic header.  Much better to use the simple `#include <iostream>`.  No need for other headers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you are right, Its just become habit  to nclude <bits/stdc++.h> to avoid  adding multiple headers while using different stl.  iostream works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is check each number starting from the next one to given number, see if it is prime. then just return the first one to be prime.

1. in nextPrime() function, we take a number starting from the next one to given number.
2. then in isPrime(), check if it is a prime.
3. if it is, return the number. else continue with the next one.

```
bool isPrime(int n) 
{ 
    // Corner case 
    if (n <= 1) 
        return false; 
  
    // Check from 2 to n-1 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) 
        if (n % i == 0) 
            return false; 
  
    return true; 
}

int nextPrime (int n){
    for (int i=n+1; i<1000000; i++){
        if (isPrime(i)) return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: checking till sqrt of a number  enough to detect a prime.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because you want to increment `num` while it is NOT a prime number. When it is not a prime number, it is divisible by something. If something is divisible by -say- N then `num % N == 0`, but you are testing for non-zero.

Instead you wanted to do:

```
// Increment num as long as it is divisible by any of these numbers.
while (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0 || num % 4 == 0 || num % 5 == 0 || num % 6 == 0 || num % 7 == 0 || num % 8 == 0 || num % 9 == 0)
  ++num;
```

Also, you did put a semi-colon after the while, causing it to loop infinitely without every changing num. Or, if num is divisible by any of the given numbers just increment num once.

Also note that there is no need to check if num is divisible by a composite number; if it is, then you will already find that it can be divided by one of its factors. For example, checking if it is divisible by 4 makes no sense, because you already found that it is divisible by 2 in that case.

Another improvement therefore would have been:

```
// Increment num while NOT "not divisible by 2 and not divisible by 3, etc".
while (!(num % 2 != 0 && num % 3 != 0 && num % 5 != 0 && num % 7 != 0) && num % 11 != 0)
  ++num;
```

Finally, then you have to realize that this is a rather bad way to code this since you are just hard coding all primes in your application this way, in which case you might as well put them all in a table and find the first one that is larger or equal than the starting value.